# HIghlight words in DOM without injecting additional Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webkit

I want specific text (ranges/nodes) in a `DOM` to be highlighted (spellchecking) without inserting additional `Nodes` into the `DOM`. Unfortunately, the solutions (I found for spellchecking) that exist out there all rely on modifying the `DOM` (adding additional `SPANs` that wrap the text ranges).

Would absolute positioning of `DIVs` with a lower z-order than the text range that has to be highlighted (for example, black text on top of a yellow background/rectangle) work? Of course, this might be problematic whenever the window/container size changes.

Do you know of any other solutions that would work?

Comment: _"Would absolute positioning of DIVs with a lower z-order ... work"_ wouldn't that go against your need of not adding nodes to the dom?

Comment: Great point! What I really mean is that I have a root node which is not to be modified, for example a DIV inside the document body (the root node which contains the text nodes) and another DIV inside the document body that contains the "markers" (style ranges). Sorry for not being specific about this.

Comment: I just don't know how you'd get the x/y coordinates of a specific word within the text node.  What is the actual problem with wrapping elements in a span?  I only ask, because if you could even temporarily wrap the elements, then you could build an array of the x/y coordinates for top/left and bottom right of each span.  In theory, then you could do what you're suggesting.  What are you trying to actually accomplish?